# Using PHP to Insert Into a Database - only inserting one row

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, insert

I am trying to insert multiple rows into a Table from a Textfile.
The code below only seems to insert the first row from the Textfile. How can I change it so that it will loop through and insert the rest of the rows?

```
$rwy = "./rwy.txt";

if (file_exists($rwy)) {
sql('TRUNCATE rwy_current');

$array = file($rwy);

foreach ($array as $line) {
    $bits = explode("\r\n", $line);
    foreach ($bits as $row) {
        $col = explode("\t", $row);
        sql("INSERT INTO rwy_current (arpt_ident, high_ident, low_ident, high_hdg, low_hdg, length, surface, pcn, he_elev, he_slope, he_tdze, le_elev, le_slope,
              le_tdze, he_true_hdg, le_true_hdg, heland_dis, he_takeoff, leland_dis, le_takeoff, cycle_date)
             VALUES ('$col[0]', '$col[1]', '$col[2]', '$col[3]', '$col[4]', '$col[5]', '$col[7]', '$col[8]', '$col[13]', '$col[14]', '$col[15]', '$col[30]',
              '$col[31]', '$col[32]', '$col[43]', '$col[44]', '$col[46]', '$col[47]', '$col[48]', '$col[49]', '$col[50]')
           ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmm, some more data but me thinks that this is a csv. You need to use the read file commands and str_getcsv commands. Either way print_r and var_dump are your friends to debug your problem

Comment: `file($rwy)` already does the `explode("\r\n")` for you, you only need the second loop with `foreach ($array as $row)`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.The Textfile is TSV and a var_dump of $row gives me: string(0) ""

Comment: You should really be doing this with a prepared statement. if even one of those values contains an unescaped single quote your query will fail. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5828/pdo/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parametrized-queries

Comment: I am aware that it is not a Prepared Statement; but as far as i am aware that shouldn't stop it from only returning one row. Should it?

Comment: if i include an IF statement at the end of the final Foreach Loop, and test for a value I know has more than one row. it returns all the data to screen that I would like to be included in the Table.
    `if ($col[0] == "UK00523") {
      echo $row;
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alter table rwy_current add primary key (arpt_ident, high_ident, low_ident);
```

Solved it

Problem was in the database; I only had one Primary Key set.